# How does U-Boot find the kernel? Does it need to know exact address

Tags: embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, bootloader, partition, u-boot

I am new to Linux programming on embedded systems. I wish to understand more about embedded bootloaders and U-boot. My main question no doubt is generic, but i'm trying to understand how U-boot finds the Linux kernel exactly.

Being more specific, I am using a BeagleBone Black. I have an SD card partitioned as follows (taken from an online example) , a FAT32 partition containing the MLO + U-Boot, an EXT4 partition containing the kernel + device tree and another EXT4 partition containing the rootfs.

I understand that the ROM primary bootloader loads first, locates the MLO file in the FAT partition which then passes control to U-Boot.

How does U-Boot then finally locate the kernel exactly? Is this related to the uEnv.txt boot configuration file? I understand that there is a learning curve with U-Boot which takes some reading, but just to get some knowledge in advance.

What happens now if I change the SD card image and put more partitions and try to boot from it, with the kernel on a different partition? Do I need to tell U-Boot specifically where to find the kernel, or will it keep searching until it finds it?

Comment: This is specific to a specific configuration.  You'll probably find info in the platform docs and may see quite a bit of hinting in the runtime output of u-boot if you have that enabled.

Answer (score 5):

You should tell the U-Boot where the kernel located and how should U-Boot load the kernel into the memory. It can be on the network, uSD card, NAND Flash, NOR Flash or another place.

There is a different configuration for the different devices. For your current u-boot, you can look the this file. It should be **am335x_evm.h** file.

```
https://github.com/antmicro/u-boot/blob/master/include/configs/am335x_evm.h
```

In the file, there are two different configuration for NAND Flash and MMC card. It tells to u-boot where kernel located, what is kernel file name, how kernel should load the memory.

Here is the configuration for NAND Flash.

```
"mtdids=" MTDIDS_DEFAULT "\0" \
"mtdparts=" MTDPARTS_DEFAULT "\0" \
"nandargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} " \
    "${optargs} " \
    "root=${nandroot} " \
    "rootfstype=${nandrootfstype}\0" \
"nandroot=ubi0:rootfs rw ubi.mtd=NAND.file-system,2048\0" \
"nandrootfstype=ubifs rootwait=1\0" \
"nandboot=echo Booting from nand ...; " \
    "run nandargs; " \
    "nand read ${fdtaddr} NAND.u-boot-spl-os; " \
    "nand read ${loadaddr} NAND.kernel; " \
    "bootz ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}\0
```

If you revise here. It tells to U-Boot it should read the **"NAND.Kernel"** file from **"${loadaddr}"** with **"nand read"** command.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

u-boot looks for kernel image at the path specified in u-boot environment file **(uEnv.txt)**. Here is the sample uEnv.txt file:

```
console=ttyO0,115200n8
ipaddr=192.168.7.2
serverip=192.168.7.1
loadaddr=0x82000000
fdtaddr=0x88000000
loadfromsd=load mmc 0:2 ${loadaddr} /boot/uImage;load mmc 0:2 ${fdtaddr} /boot/am335x-boneblack.dtb
linuxbootargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw 
uenvcmd=setenv autoload no; run loadfromsd; run linuxbootargs; bootm ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}
```

As you can see load address for Root File System & Device Tree has been define and environment variable has been declared mentioning the path of the kernel image.

U-boot will read boot arguments from this file.

Comment: How does U-Boot know the size of kernel?

Comment: @DanielSelvan if reading from something like NAND I suspect it would figure out the size from headers, if no header then perhaps you need to provide size. But if you are booting from a filesystem then it can determine the file size in the usual way.